# Size of long in C++

Tags: c++

After searching on the Internet, I found out (correct me if I am wrong) that on Windows compilers, both ints and longs are 32 bits long, but on most Linux compilers ints are 32 bit and longs are 64 bit.

If I use GCC on Linux to make a Windows executable, when I run it on Windows will the longs still be 64 bits long or will they only be 32 bits large? If not, how can I force a long to be 64 bits long on all architectures/OSs/compilers?

Also, if I use 32 bit GCC or compile for a 32 bit architecture, will longs still be 64 bits or will they become 32 bits?

Comment: "Windows compilers, both ints and longs are 32 bits long, but on most Linux compilers ints are 32 bit and longs are 64 bit."  actually, it depends on which windows compiler you're using.  msvc comes with a 32 and a 64 bit compiler.   try the 64-bit version and update your post.

Comment: @thang even with 64-bit compiles on MSVC the `long` type is 32 bits.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I don't understand your purpose in saying that.  Did I say that 64-bit MSVC use 64-bit longs?  I must be missing something...

Comment: @thang, yes that's exactly what I thought you were saying. Even re-reading it now I don't see how to interpret it any differently. You seem to say that the size of `long` in MSVC depends on whether you're doing a 32 or 64 bit build.

Comment: @MarkRansom, re-read it... can you find the exact statement where I said that?  I never made a statement about the size of long.

Comment: @thang, you quoted the assertion in the question that on Windows compilers ints and longs were both 32 bits long. Then you said "try the 64-bit version (of msvc) and update your post." I can only assume you expected the result to be different. I simply pointed out that it wouldn't be.

Comment: @thang I also thought that you meant longs would be 64 bits with a 64 bit MSVC++. I don't really see what else it could mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 defined [fixed width integers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), which you can use by including `<cstdint>`. Instead of using an `int` or a `long`, you can use an `int32_t`, for example. Similar functionality exists in C99's `<stdint.h>`.

If those aren't an option, you can create your own header by doing something like.

```
#ifdef PLATFORM1
typedef int myint64
...
#endif
#ifdef PLATFORM2
typedef long myint64
...
#endif
```

Then in Platform 1's makefile, pass in `-DPLATFORM1`, and in Platform 2's makefile, pass in `-DPLATFORM2`

Comment: If I use a normal long and compile with GCC so that the long is 64 bits at compile time, will it still be 64 bits when running on a Windows computer?

Comment: no, the cross-compiler from linux to windows will also use 32 bit for long